# sublime text: view off-screen multiple selections

Tags: sublimetext, multiple-select

When I do a multiple selection from, say, the find dialog (Alt-Enter), I sometimes find that many of the selected bits are off screen, but I'd like to check the context of all of them before I start doing a multiple edit.

Is there a way to, say, cycle through them in the view (without disrupting the selections)?

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to not do a "Find All", but instead highlight (or do a single Find) what you're looking for, then use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on OS X/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> on Win/Lin to sequentially add the next matches. If you come to a match you don't want to select, just use <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>,<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>) to skip the current instance and go on to the next one. <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>) is "soft undo", it moves back to the previous selection in case you made a mistake.

Alternatively, I use a [color scheme](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) with a very bright selection color (it's bright blue surrounded by bright green) so that selected regions are very easy to identify. This way I can just glance at the minimap and see where selections are, and scroll through my file quickly to ensure everything looks good. If you find a selection you don't want, you can deselect it with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+middle mouse button on Win/Lin, or by <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd>+click on OS X. You may need to set `"drag_text": false` in your Preferences for it to work, though (I'm not on my Mac at the moment to test).

Comment: The alt-mid-btn I didn't know - thx. Is there something like ctrl-d that works with regular expressions? alt-etner from the select dialog does a find-all using a regex, but I've not found a way to do that incrementally...

Comment: @drevicko - Yes, you can use `Ctrl-D` and `Ctrl-K,Ctrl-D` while the find dialog is open. Type in your regex, and all the potential matches are outlined. Without hitting `Alt-Enter`, use `Ctrl-D` and `Ctrl-K,Ctrl-D` to step through, selecting and skipping as you want. Then, once everything is selected, hit `Esc` to dismiss the Find dialog and you should be left with your multiple selections. I just tested this in ST3 on XP, so I don't know about other versions/platforms yet, but hopefully it should work with them, too.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work for me - it searches for one of the mathces (as a literal string) or a word around the cursor. I suspect alt-middle-click is getting trapped by the OS - it changes the cursor to "drag left edge", and does nothing in sublime text..

Comment: Hmm, I didn't try clicking to deselect. Here's exactly what I did - I opened up my `Preferences.sublime-settings` file, which is quite lengthy. I did a regex search using `Ctrl-F` for `['"]` to find all single- and double-quotes. I then used `Ctrl-D` to select the first few matches, `Ctrl-K, Ctrl-D` to skip a couple randomly, then `Ctrl-D` to get a few more for good measure. I then hit `Esc`, and I was left with the multi-selections I chose - there was no clicking at all during that time.

Comment: when I do that, the search string changes to just `"` (ie: no regex), and subsequently single quotes aren't found..

Comment: I've tried to disable the OS grabbing alt-middle-button, not sure if I succeeded (it doesn't resize the window any more though). In any case, it doesn't do anything in ST either ): btw: I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 running unity, my ST is build 3047 - ST3 I think, but it doesn't tell me that..

Answer (score 0):

I've found a working solution, but it's not ideal and only works if you're ok with losing the selections (eg: with multiple selections, hit <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> - you've still got multiple cursors, but the selections are gone).

It goes like this:

1. Make sure there is no code folding - it appears to interfere with this sort of manipulation of multiple selections.
2. Use <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> in the search dialogue to select all occurrences of your regex.
3. Scroll through the selections until you find one you don't want (MattDMo's [Neon](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Neon%20Color%20Scheme) plugin is helpful here).
4. Use a cursor movement to lose the selections (multiple cursors remain).
5. Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left Click on the undesired cursor.
6. Repeat 5. as required. Making another (multiple) selection can be helpful here to locate the other cursors (eg: <kbd>Control/Command</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>)
7. If you remove a cursor by mistake, or need to add one, use <kbd>Control/Command</kbd>+Left Click